# Typo and about the book search

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, spelling

If I add a book to the read books on the careers site, I should be able to search by ISBN; at least the text tells me I can. But neither ISBN-10 nor ISBN-13 worked; search by title did. If it does not find anything at least it could tell me that nothing has been found. I've search the TDD book by [Pryce and Freeman](http://www.amazon.de/Growing-Object-Oriented-Software-Guided-Signature/dp/0321503627/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1424929185&sr=8-1&keywords=growing+object-oriented+software+guided+by+tests). As a sidenote, searching by title returns a lot of duplicates.

Then, when I add a comment to a read book, the save link is spelled *Speichern)* in german. The trailing parenthesis should not be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report!

It would appear that search by ISBN was working just fine in English but was failing miserably in French and German.

We use the Amazon Product Search API to search for items in the 'Books' search index. When using the .de or .fr top-level domains to perform this search Amazon will only search books written in that language! To find English-language books using the API we needed to also search the 'ForeignBooks' index.

We now do this if the initial search across 'Books' doesn't produce any results; you can now search for ISBN and it'll work.

Oh and I removed the extra parenthesis too :)